# How can I pressurize water to make my own pressure washer?

Tags: pressure-washer

COVID19 unemployed my family, and I don't want spend [at least $100](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Outdoors-Outdoor-Power-Equipment-Pressure-Washers-Electric-Pressure-Washers/Light-Duty/N-5yc1vZ2fkooyrZ1z1caoa?storeSelection=1287,1233,1234,1268,1228&experienceName=default) on Electric Light Duty pressure washer. What can I try first?

How can I modify my [high pressure plastic spray bottle](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Outdoors-Garden-Center-Sprayers/SOLO/0/N-5yc1vZcalkZad5Z1z0tqc2?storeSelection=1287,1233,1234,1268,1228), if it doesn't pressurize water enough? [Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/HDX-1-Gal-Pump-Sprayer-1501HDXA/307766754) has manual pump sprayer, but I don't know if it pressurizes water more than my spray bottle.

Comment: what do you want to wash?

Comment: i read your post again ... it seems to me that you should try out your pressure bottle first, then ask a question about modifying it if it is unsatisfactory ... asking questions about modification, before trying the bottle, is kind of pointless

Comment: I don't believe you can. A typical garden sprayer (pump sprayer) is between 40 psi and 200 psi (professional exterminator type) a normal pressure washer is anywhere from 1000 psi up to 4000 psi and more. You cannot put those pressures in a plastic pump sprayer.

Comment: Start by describing what you need to accomplish. What are you trying to wash?